# Use class instantiation to return an instance of a subclass? (for ABC in particular)

Tags: python

## In one sentence

Is there a way to use class instantiation to return an instance of a subclass? (for ABC in particular)

## Setup

I have an abstract base class with several sub-classes, which I can instantiate and use just fine. Here a reduced (and nonsensical) example to illustrate:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC
from typing import Iterable


class Entity(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def describe(self) -> str:
        ...


class Person(Entity):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    def describe(self):
        return f"Hi I am {self.name}."


class Group(Entity):
    def __init__(self, names: Iterable[str]):
        self.names = names

    def describe(self):
        return f'Hello we are {" and ".join(self.names)}.'


p1 = Person("Alice")
g1 = Group(["Bob", "Chris"])
```

## "Issue" and current solution

I don't always know in advance if I need a `Person` or a `Group`, and determine this in code. A function returns an instance of the appropriate class:

```py
def create_entity(name_or_names: Union[str, Iterable[str]]):
    if isinstance(name_or_names, str):
        return Person(name_or_names)
    else:
        return Group(name_or_names)

p2 = create_entity("Alice")
g2 = create_entity(["Bob", "Chris"])
```

This works just fine as well.

## Code review questions

I would prefer to keep the 'class instantiation pattern' as used for `p1` and `g1`, but by using a **common** class. In other words, I'd rather write something like this

```py
p3 = Entity("Alice") # returns Person 
g3 = Entity(["Bob", "Chris"]) # returns Group
```

so that it's clear I'm creating an object.

It feels like an antipattern to me to have a function, like `create_entity` here, return a class instance.

- Am I being silly?
- If no, is there a sensible way to do this? Either as part of the ABC itself or as part of a dedicated 'switchboard' subclass of the ABC.

I could go against naming conventions and simply rename the function to `Entity` (or something similar, to avoid a name collision) but that too doesn't sit right.

Many thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: We don't review "reduced and nonsensical examples"; we review real code. If you're able to show this code in its full, realistic context, it can be on-topic. As it is, it's too hypothetical to answer.

Comment: @Reinderien IMO it's not "_too hypothetical to answer_". This question seem to have everything it needs for a reasonable answer :)

Comment: I try to distill my questions to the point where they show the issue I'm dealing with, and only that. I could post the whole code, but it's a couple of 100 lines long, require a detailed explanation to its purpose if you are not familiar with the industry it's to be used in, and would generally really detract from the core coding 'style' question I'd like reviewed.

Comment: Your strategy is a good one for StackOverflow, but this is not StackOverflow - we love to see your code; and we love to see it in its entirety. A couple of hundred lines is quite easily digestible. The "distillation" process you describe is akin to the MCVE principal, and that's an SO-ism and not a CRSE-ism. The further you distill your code, the fewer hints we have as to why a thing exists the way it does, and the less meaningful commentary we can offer about your application design.

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex Since the point of Code Review is to review code and help people improve their coding ability and not to answer how to questions, Reinderien is correct. There is obviously missing code which is a problem for a good code review.

Comment: You might want to look up factory patterns to see how other people have done this.

Comment: I didn't post it to stackoverflow as the code _is_ working. But I'll try my luck over there then, anyway. I can't post the whole code here as I'm already in the middle of refactoring, to which I was hoping this question could contribute ;)

Comment: I don't subscribe to the view that we need to see "all" of your code. Sometimes most of the code is irrelevant to the key issues, and we have no independent way to know whether the "all" standard has been truly met. However, **we do need enough code and context to understand purpose and goals**. Currently, we lack that because the Group class has no reason to exist: it's just a list of Person, plus a toy method. What actual data or behavior justifies the existence of Group? I voted to close the question for that reason but would reconsider, given more context.